# I have an Azure blob link of image but I am not able to see the preview when I click on that image it is directly downloading the image

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

Details: I have an Azure blob link of an image, but I am not able to see the preview when I click on that image, it is directly downloading the image and not showing the image preview.

Result: when I will click on blob link, it should first show a preview, then it should download in Angular or ASP.NET MVC.

My task is to show that image in pdf but I am not able to see the preview. Is there any way to convert that blob link into the normal image link? I have to show that image in pdf but through code I am not able to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Because the file you're trying to display in the browser doesn't have the correct MIME type set, the browser defaults to treating it as `application/octet-stream`, which results in it being downloaded. If you want to enable file preview when clicking a link, you need to set the appropriate property for the blob, for example:

```cs
blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
```

This will make the browser recognize the MIME type of the file as an image and attempt to display it in the default preview.

However, this issue is in no way related to embedding using HTML tags like `<img>` or in a PDF but rather with the browser's behavior. If you embed this image anywhere using the appropriate mechanisms, even without changing the MIME type, it should display correctly.